# jekyll work in local but not work github. File to import not found or unreadable: minima

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

My Code.
https://github.com/shingo-nakanishi/jekyll-dojo/tree/03e7541c602daab320b18ec7545e4259433dcaf4

jekyll work in local but not work github.

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> Your SCSS file `css/main.scss` has an error on line 36: File to import not found or unreadable: minima. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-invalid-sass-or-scss.

Why work in local? How to work in github?

Answer (score 6):

Jekyll 3.2 use gem based themes but github pages is still at version 3.1.X.

You have to first locate your minima gem :

```
bundle show minima
```

Will give you something like `/very/long/path/to/2.2.0/gems/minima-1.0.1`. You can then copy/paste _includes, _layouts and _sass folders from your gem to your site root from the file explorer.

Or you can do it with the command line from your root :

```
cd your/root/folder
cp -R `echo "$(bundle show minima)/_*/"` .
cp -R `echo "$(bundle show minima)/assets/"` .
```

Your site will now work on gh pages. And theme gem is now useless, because overridden by copied files.

Comment: This is definitely the root of the problem, but for some reason even doing this still results in a build error on the line `@import "minima";` in `main.scss` despite `minima.scss` being in the same directory and compiling without errors.

Comment: `_includes, _layouts and _sass` folders from gem must be copied at the root of your site. `minima.scss` must be in `_sass` folder like other scss files, except `css/main.scss`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: So, maybe you can approve my answer.

Comment: No worries. Thanks again!

Comment: It might be nice to either explain what this command does cp -R `echo "$(bundle show minima)/_*/"` . or provide a way to add the path manually. The oneliner is hard to read and you can easily miss the "." at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Github Pages does not have the gem `minima` available to it. You'll have to manually import that into your repo

Comment: Clone the https://github.com/jekyll/minima/tree/master/_sass tree and take all files and directories from `_sass` and place them in `css` in your repo

Comment: I try. https://github.com/shingo-nakanishi/jekyll-dojo/tree/d8a9ae677704c42ed0867b62afc28efdd81ad64c

same error.

Comment: You moved bootstrap into your repo, not minima

Comment: I try minima this commit https://github.com/shingo-nakanishi/jekyll-dojo/tree/d8a9ae677704c42ed0867b62afc28efdd81ad64c but not work(same error). I give up minima.

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi As David noted in the comments below his answer, the `minima` and `minima.scss` files go in a folder called `_sass` in your root directory. Moving the files there and keeping `main.scss` in the `css` directory solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you used other theme for your blog, if that so, after you create new Jekyll blog, the default theme is 'minima'. If you copied other theme from the zip file, most of them have the css file inside 'public' folder. So just remove your default 'css' folder that existed after created new Jekyll blog because the actual 'css' file that you'll use is inside 'public' folder created by theme author.
Hope this help.