# Jekyll blog shows 404 error

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I created a simple jekyll site as https://github.com/nagachinta/nagachinta.github.io, but throws 404 error. I observed the git commits I made and the commits in the git says.

" A file was included in about.md that is a symlink , doesnot exist in your '_includes', directory."

The file is not a symlink, it's just a real file.

The index files , etc are real files not symlinks.

Comment: This type of question isn't what stackoverflow is for. Stackoverflow isn't a free debugging service.

Comment: @BryanOakley if you take a look at Jekyll's thread right now, you will see that some major changes are bringing some troubles to "not so geek" users. Transition from 3.1 to 3.2 is not easy and is not very well documented when it comes to use 3.2 on github pages. And after all, we are here to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Jekyll 3.2 locally. This means that you're now using [gem based themes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/). No more _includes, _layouts and _sass folder when you do your `jekyll new`.

On the other side github pages uses Jekyll 3.1.6 ([reference](https://rubygems.org/gems/github-pages/versions/91)).

So when you pull a site created without _includes, _layouts and _sass folders on github pages, it results in build errors. Your site is not created and you get 404s errors.

If you want to be sure that a site developed locally to work on github pages, you can go with gh-pages gems. [See install instructions here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/).

If you just want to stay with jekyll 3.2 locally and copy themes's files, you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38801882/1548376).